# Migration Error going from Struts 2.3 to 2.5

Tags: struts2

I have a legacy app and I have to update struts 2.3 to struts 2.5. I have followed the migration instructions here (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration) but I am getting the following error in Weblogic:

org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler - Exception occurred during processing request: Cannot find definition named '/menu.tiles'

According to the migration instructions above, I only have to change the DOCTYPE in my struts.xml and tiles.xml files.

I tried the solution here ([org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: Cannot find definition named 'addCustomer.tiles'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895009/org-apache-tiles-definition-nosuchdefinitionexception-cannot-find-definition-na)) but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

All, I found this on stack overflow and it solved my issue. I am posting the answer so the next guy doesn't spend days looking for the answer.

The accepted answer from the link below solved my problem. *Note - I am working with Weblogic 12.4
[Runtime exception while upgrading to struts 2.5.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292594/runtime-exception-while-upgrading-to-struts-2-5-17)